# Eclipse Check for Updates says "The operation cannot be completed"

Tags: eclipse

I tried to update Eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0) to the latest release and getting the following failure -

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.4.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20220904-1703)
  Software currently installed: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.4.4.20201128-1705)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core 2.0.3.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 2.0.3.20220904-1703)
    Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.18.1.20210614-1604 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.18.1.20210614-1604)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.4.20220904-1703 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20220904-1703)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.core [2.0.3.20220904-1703,2.0.3.20220904-1703]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven JPA Configurator 1.4.4.20201128-1705 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa 1.4.4.20201128-1705)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.4.4.20201128-1705)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa [1.4.4.20201128-1705,1.4.4.20201128-1705]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP" that you already have installed doesn't seem to be compatible with the version of "M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse" in the update. You probably need to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't install "M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse" manually, it is packaged with "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers". As suggested I uninstalled it. Now I am getting the following failure -

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: SWT Tools 3.108.600.v20220826-1037 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.group 3.108.600.v20220826-1037)
  Software currently installed: SWT Tools Developer Resources 3.108.300.v20211104-1108 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.source.feature.group 3.108.300.v20211104-1108)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    SWT Tools 3.108.600.v20220826-1037 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.jar 3.108.600.v20220826-1037)
    SWT Tools 3.108.300.v20211104-1108 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.jar 3.108.300.v20211104-1108)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SWT Tools 3.108.300.v20211104-1108 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.group 3.108.300.v20211104-1108)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.jar [3.108.300.v20211104-1108,3.108.300.v20211104-1108]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SWT Tools 3.108.600.v20220826-1037 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.group 3.108.600.v20220826-1037)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.jar [3.108.600.v20220826-1037,3.108.600.v20220826-1037]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SWT Tools Developer Resources 3.108.300.v20211104-1108 (org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.source.feature.group 3.108.300.v20211104-1108)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature.feature.group [3.108.300.v20211104-1108,3.108.300.v20211104-1108]
```

For testing purpose I tried to update a freshly downloaded 2021-09 (4.21.0) and getting the following failure -

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Git integration for Eclipse 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
  Software currently installed: Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface 5.13.0.202109080827-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 5.13.0.202109080827-r)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Git integration for Eclipse - Core 5.13.0.202109080827-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 5.13.0.202109080827-r)
    Git integration for Eclipse - Core 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git integration for Eclipse 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.egit.core [6.3.0.202209071007-r,6.3.0.202209071007-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface 5.13.0.202109080827-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 5.13.0.202109080827-r)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui [5.13.0.202109080827-r,5.13.0.202109080827-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Mylyn UI 5.13.0.202109080827-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui 5.13.0.202109080827-r)
    To: java.package; org.eclipse.egit.core [5.13.0,5.14.0)
```